# Merge Sort for linked list implementation in python is not working

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

Can someone please help me figure out what went wrong with this code? The code is printing the first node in the linked list instead of the sorted linked list.

```
    class LinkedList(object):  
      def __init__(self):  
      self.head = None  

     class Node(object):
        def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def push(self, new_data):
       new_node = self.Node(new_data)
       new_node.next = self.head
       self.head = new_node

    def print_list(self):
       temp = self.head
       while(temp):
          print temp.data
          temp = temp.next
```

## merge two sorted lists

```
def merge_lists(head1, head2):

   if(head1 is None):
      return head2
   if(head2 is None):
      return head1

   s = t= LinkedList.Node(None)

   while(head1 and head2):
     if(head1.data <= head2.data):
        c= head1
        head1 = head1.next
     else:
        c= head2
        head2 = head2.next

     t.next = c 
     t = t.next
  t.next = head1 or head2
  return s.next
```

## split the linked list

```
def front_back_split(head):
   if(head is None or head.next is None):
      head1 = head
      head2 = None
   else:
      slow = head
      fast = head.next
      while(fast != None):
         fast = fast.next
         if(fast!=None):
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next

   head1 = head
   head2 = slow.next
   slow.next = None

   return head1, head2
```

## merge sort

```
def merge_sort(head):
   if(head is None or head.next is None):
      return 

   a,b = front_back_split(head)


   merge_sort(a)
   merge_sort(b)

   new_head = merge_lists(a,b)

   return new_head
```

### main

```
if __name__=='__main__':
   llist1 = LinkedList()
   llist1.push(6)
   llist1.push(7)
   llist1.push(1)
   llist1.push(4)
   llist1.push(3)
   llist1.push(8)



   print "Sorted list"
   new_head = merge_sort(llist1.head)
   llist1.print_list()
```

Comment: What's the smallest data it doesn't work with?

Comment: `s = t = LinkedList.Node(None)` means `s` and `t` both point at the same object. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes. this code will keep on adding new nodes to the tail of the linked list using t.next and s.next points to the head of the linked list.

Comment: my input linked list was 8->3->4->1->7->6 and it returned 8->3->4

Comment: but `t.next` and `s.next` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This response applies to an earlier version of the code.  See my new response for fixes for the new version of the code.

Ok, it looks like the problem is the way you're returning linked lists from functions.  In `front_to_back_split`, you're assigning to `head1` and `head2`, but those are just parameters to the function.  I.e., they're local variables.  Assigning to them has no effect on the caller.

A better way to do it is to eliminate `head1` and `head2` as arguments, and instead just make them ordinary local variables.  Then change it to return `head1` and `head2`, like so:

```
return head1, head2
```

Then, in `merge_sort`, you no longer need to allocate `a` and `b`.  Instead, you can just do:

```
a, b = front_to_back_split(head)
```

Similarly, `merge_sort` should return the new `head` so the caller can use it.  Otherwise the caller has no way to determine what the new list head is.

Comment: made the changes. Now my code prints only the first element. Same logic worked in C.

Comment: If you can show the new code, I'll find the problem for you.

Comment: See my new answer, which fixes the new version of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've debugged your updated version and it now works.  There are three changes:

1. At the top of `merge_sort` there's a bare `return`.  Change it to:

   ```
   return head
   ```
2. In `merge_sort`, change the recursive calls so that they update `a` and `b`, as follows:

   ```
   a = merge_sort(a)
   b = merge_sort(b)
   ```
3. In your main code, after sorting the list, you need a `LinkedList` with the new head in order to print it, since `llist1` will still point to the old head.  You can use this:

   ```
   print "Sorted list"
   new_head = merge_sort(llist1.head)
   new_list = LinkedList()
   new_list.head = new_head
   new_list.print_list()
   ```

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner to python and this ans helped me